# Cannot use relative path when using 'Execute Line in Console' in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm for python project. My project structure is like this:

```
+ project
  + src
    - Data.csv
    - main.py
```

This is `main.py`:

```
import panda as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
```

When i use 'Execute Line in Console' and run the second line, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-bd7168d85704>", line 1, in <module>
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\livw2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Data.csv' does not exist: b'Data.csv'
```

When i run the whole code using 'Run', it's fine, so i think that executing in console changes the directory. But i haven't figured out how to fix.

Comment: Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console -> Working directory. You will have to end the old console if there's still one running (even if it's hidden) before the change will take effect. Or you can just do `import os` and then `os.chdir("path/you/want/to/change/to")` in the console.

Comment: @blubberdiblub thank you, your commend is really helpful. I realize that the console is setting for the whole project when we use 'Execute Line in Console', which means the project's directory will be current directory. We can run a line in a file, then choose some lines in another file to run, in only one console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, just close your current project and open another project which contain your file directly.